# Custom View under nav bar but above tableview

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have searched all of the internet for a solution and cannot seem to get this to work!

I am looking to add a view below a navigation bar but above a tableview and the view will always be visible, including when you scroll down.

This will work a lot like many apps that use a segmented control for extra sorting options, but I will be using my own custom buttons instead of a UISegmentedControl

Here is an example:
[image]

I have attempted adding the view to the talbeView header, but it scrolls. I have attempted adding it with a UIBarButtonItem added to a tool bar, and I have tried adding it to the view the tableview is in (which is a navigation controller).

The basic setup of my app is a nav bar, then a search bar that is attached to the tableview, and of course the table view. This is all done programmatically and I cannot make any adjustments wit IB. Is there any way to properly achieve this? Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: So you are not pushing a `UIViewController` into the `UINavigationController`? Please show your adding code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use most outside view as scrollView

```
scrollView
    -segmentView
    -tableView
```

then

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView{
    if(scrollView.contentOffset>0){
        segmentView.frame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    }
}
```